# Update column if date between 2 dates in another Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here are my 2 data frames:
df1

```
eid start_dt   end_dt     flag
1   2020-12-01 2020-12-07 0
1   2020-12-08 2020-12-15 0
1   2020-12-16 2020-12-23 1
2   2020-12-01 2020-12-07 0
```

df2

```
eid event_dt   col1 col2
1   2020-12-01 .    .
1   2020-12-09 .    .
1   2020-12-17 .    .
2   2020-12-02 .    .
```

output df.

```
- If in df1 and df2,  the eids match AND event_dt is between start_dt,end_dt
 -- add a new column 
 -- update the flag
```

The output data frame df would look like this

```
eid event_dt   col1 col2 flag
1   2020-12-01 .    .    0
1   2020-12-09 .    .    0
1   2020-12-17 .    .    1
2   2020-12-02 .    .    0
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `merge` and `query`:

```
df2['flag'] = (df1.assign(idx=df1.index)
    .merge(df2, on='eid', how='left')
    .query('start_dt <= event_dt <= end_dt')
    .set_index('idx')
    ['flag']
)
```

Output:

```
   eid    event_dt col1 col2  flag
0    1  2020-12-01    .    .     0
1    1  2020-12-09    .    .     0
2    1  2020-12-17    .    .     1
3    2  2020-12-02    .    .     0
```

---

**Update**: For the bigger dataset, the above approach may yield a `MemoryError`. Use `pd.merge_asof` instead:

```
df2['flag'] = (pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('event_dt'),
                             df1.assign(idx=df1.index).sort_values('end_dt'),
                             by='eid', left_on='event_dt',
                             right_on='start_dt')
               .query('event_dt<=end_dt')
               .set_index('idx')
               ['flag']
               )
```

Comment: I get an memory error KeyError: MemoryError((150, 23288619), dtype('int64'))

Comment: Sorry I get another error - ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis